# Apache Beam - Parallelize Google Cloud Storage Blob Downloads While Maintaining Grouping of Blobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I’d like to be able to maintain a grouping of entities within a single `PCollection` element, but parallelize the fetching of those entities from Google Cloud Storage (GCS). i.e.`PCollection<Iterable<String>>` --> `PCollection<Iterable<String>>` where the starting `PCollection` is an Iterable of file paths and the resulting `PCollection` is Iterable of file contents. Alternatively, `PCollection<String> --> PCollection<Iterable<String>>` would also work and perhaps even be preferable, where the starting `PCollection` is a glob pattern, and the resulting `PCollection` is an iterable of file contents which matched the glob.

My use-case is that at a point in my pipeline I have as input  `PCollection<String>`. Each element of the `PCollection` is a GCS glob pattern. It’s important that files which match the glob be grouped together because the content of the files–once all files in a group are read–need to be grouped downstream in the pipeline. I originally tried using `FileIO.matchAll`  and a subsequently `GroupByKey` . However, the matchAll, window, and `GroupByKey` combination lacked any guarantee that all files matching the glob would be read and in the same window before performing the GroupByKey transform (though I may be misunderstanding Windowing). It’s possible to achieve the desired results if a large time span `WindowFn` is applied, but it’s still probabilistic rather than a guarantee that all files will be read before grouping. It’s also the main goal of my pipeline to maintain the lowest possible latency.

So my next, and currently operational, plan was to use an `AsyncHttpClient` to fan out fetching file contents via GCS HTTP API. I feel like this goes against the grain in Beam and is likely  sub-optimal in terms of parallelization.

So I’ve started investigating SplittableDoFn . My current plan is to allow splitting such that each entity in the input Iterable (i.e. each matched file from the glob pattern) could be processed separately. I've been able to modify `FileIO#MatchFn` ([defined here in the Java SDK](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.28.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L650-L666)) to provide mechanics for `PCollection<String> -> PCollection<Iterable<String>>` transform between input of GCS glob patterns and output of Iterable of matches for the glob.

The challenge I’ve encountered is: how do I go about grouping/gathering the split invocations back into a single output value in my `DoFn`? I’ve tried using stateful processing and using a `BagState` to collect file contents along the way, but I realized part way along that the `ProcessElement` method of a splittable `DoFn` may only accept `ProcessContext` and `Restriction` tuples, and no other args therefore no `StateId` args referring to a `StateSpec` (throws an invalid argument error at runtime).

I noticed in the `FilePatternWatcher` example in the official [SDF proposal doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AQmx-T9XjSi1PNoEp5_L-lT0j7BkgTbmQnc6uFEMI4c/edit#heading=h.19qhdetat7d9) that a custom tracker was created wherein `FilePath` Objects kept in a set and presumably added to the set via `tryClaim`. This seems as though it could work for my use-case, but I don’t see/understand how to go about implementing a `@SplitRestriction` method using a custom `RestrictionTracker`.

I would be very appreciative if anyone were able to offer advice. I have no preference for any particular solution, only that I want to achieve the ability to maintain a grouping of entities within a single `PCollection` element, but parallelize the fetching of those entities from Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

Answer (score 1):

Would joining the output PCollections help you?

```
PCollectionList
    .of(collectionOne)
    .and(collectionTwo)
    .and(collectionThree)
    ...
    .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, there is only a singular PCollection. So I don't believe I can use this approach, unless I'm misunderstanding.